# Downloading and Uploading images automatically

Tags: python

I have a ton of transferring of images I need to do from one LMS (Learning Management system) to another and I was wondering if there was a way to automate the downloading of images and the uploading them into a different website under the same question number. Ex, I have an image in question 19 of one LMS and I need that same picture in question 19 in the other LMS. Both these LMS's are old and you cannot just export out the banks of questions with the images intact.

I am fairly new at programming, just started to learn recently. I know you can scrape images but both of these you will need to log in and navigate to the course and then the banks of questions itself. I have no idea if its possible or not.

Thanks!

Comment: yes. pretty much any task you do in a browser can be automated.

Comment: http://scrapy.org/

Comment: You can probably just do it with requests. Send a post login request, save the cookies. Send requests to all the pictures (sending your cookies) parse the HTML with BeautifulSoup, find the image, then use another request to download the image. If you want more specific help you would have to show the website